# Quant Interview Question - Probability

Tags: probability

I had an interview for quant researcher position yesterday and it was quite tricky.

[4-player game]

1st: 3point /
2nd: 1point /
3rd: 0point /
4th: -3point /

and Player A's win rate for each rank is 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%.

Question 1: What is the probability of expected sum of points Player A gets after 4th round of the game is larger than 5?

Question 2: What is the probability of expected sum of points Player A gets after n'th rounds of the game is larger than 0?

I could easily get the answer for Q1 using the concept of permutation/combination on jupyter but failed at generallizing to n'th round.

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

The expected sum of points
$$
\begin{align}
E(x)
&=\sum x p(x)\\
&=0.1\times 3+0.2\times 1+0.3\times 0+0.4\times -3\\
&=-0.7
\end{align}
$$
so after four rounds one would expect $-2.8$ points and after $n$ rounds one would expect $-0.7n$ points.

> I could easily get the answer for Q1 using the concept of permutation/combination on jupyter but failed at generallizing to n'th round.

You don't need any of these things as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh I skipped an important part while summarizing - just edited, I'm so sorry and thanks for your answer !